# Laravel, NPM: Command "mix" not found

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-8, laravel-mix

Does anyone have an idea why it throws the following error and how to fix it? I have also tried to reinstall all packages using `npm install` several times. Reinstalling NodeJS on Windows didn't work; I'm using Laravel 8.22.0.

[image]

**Full Log**

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'D:\\Programme\\NodeJS\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'D:\\Programme\\NodeJS\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'run',
0 verbose cli   'development'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.3.0
2 info using node@v15.5.1
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:file:D:\Programme\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:file:D:\My\Path\.npmrc 33,,,,,,,,Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Privat\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Privat\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
19 verbose npm-session 8b04ab779a67efab
20 timing npm:load Completed in 18ms
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 23ms
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
(D:\Programme\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:295:5)
23 verbose cwd D:\My\Path
24 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
25 verbose argv "D:\\Programme\\NodeJS\\node.exe" "D:\\Programme\\NodeJS\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "development"
26 verbose node v15.5.1
27 verbose npm  v7.3.0
28 error code 1
29 error path D:\My\Path\IDE
30 error command failed
31 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c mix
32 verbose exit 1
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.5",
        "less": "^3.12.2",
        "less-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "7.*",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
        "uglify-js": "^3.10.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! According to the [laravel-mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/586d1f2f5b51dfe5de4ef96b174c35c25b2ab3b2/docs/installation.md) docs you have to run mix via `npx mix`.

Answer (score 95):

I tried many solutions but only this worked for me:

First, update your laravel-mix

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest
```

Then do a clean npm install:

```
npm clean-install
```

that should fix the laravel 8 mix error.

Answer (score 27):

In case somebody has a similar issue.

NPM is moody. Sometimes it's worth to try deleting all modules and install them again:

on Linux it's a simple command: `rm -rf node_modules` in a project root folder,

than just run `npm install` again.

Comment: i can confirm this

Comment: Better than reinstalling laravel mix and running clean install.

Comment: Nice job, these fixes are always the simplest and work well

Answer (score 10):

You will need to bump your Laravel Mix, SASS Loader dependencies to the latest and install PostCSS and Webpack.

```
npm i --save-dev laravel-mix@latest && 
npm i --save-dev sass-loader@latest && 
npm i --save-dev postcss@latest && 
npm i --save-dev webpack@latest
```

You should now have Laravel Mix version 6, so the only remaining step is to compile your assets. Then, use the new Mix executable or use npm.

```
npx mix -p
```

**OR**

```
npm run prod
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.9",
        "less": "^3.12.2",
        "less-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.2.4",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "uglify-js": "^3.10.3",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
        "webpack": "^5.14.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add webpack.mix.js also to your answer

Answer (score 4):

> Best method to fix *mix not found error* is to reinstall npm using the command:
>
>  `npm clean-install`

Comment: This one worked for me, but i also ran npm install -g npm@latest before i ran npm clean-install

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This command alone worked and did not add anything new to commit to git either.

Answer (score 1):

Recently laravel mix has been update to laravel mix 6 so I would advise to check the current version of npm/node you are using and the try to upgrade it to the latest version.

```
npm -v
```

You can upgrade to the latest version of npm using:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Or upgrade to the most recent release:

```
npm install -g npm@next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest
```

and you may need to install vue-loader legacy peer dependencies. Generally it gets installed or updated automatically during `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1):

please run this command . Its works for me.

```
yarn install --ignore-engines
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (Win 10 as host and Homestead in Vagrant). I tried the above but still got the error. The following ended up working for me:

1. open up powershell as admin
2. navigate to project root
3. run this command

```
node c:\<path to node installation>\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
```

In previous versions installing node packages from the vm into the mounted drive (with no bin links because windows) was okay, laravel mix would work. My guess is because the package.json file was more verbose and specified full paths - [difference in package.json files here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#update-your-npm-scripts).

With the terse syntax in the new version it needs the bin link to follow the reference. Running the command without admin privileges failed for me because renaming files, might be different for you. Going forward this will need to be the new process for installing node packages (on host vs on vm).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing `laravel/ui`:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

In this case there are two possible solutions:

1. Simply delete the `node_modules` folder with `RMDIR "FOLDERNAME" /S /Q` and reinstall it with `npm install`
2. run `npm install` only
   after `laravel/ui` and `ui vue` has installed (i know, sounds crazy,
   but that's exactly how it was for me)

After you have done one of the two points, do `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation. After couple of hours finally got it working. What I did:

1. Updated NPM `npm install -g npm@latest`
2. Updated laravel-mix (6.0.31 at the moment of writing)
3. Updated Vagrantfile https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#symbolic-links-on-windows
4. Reload PC (`vagrant reload --provision`  would probably be enough)
5. Run terminal/phpstorm as admin
6. Remove old node_modules, yarn.lock, package.lock, clear NPM cache
7. IMPORTANT Use YARN! `sudo yarn install` then `sudo yarn run dev`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Node solved the problem for me, from 12 to 18. Can be a solution for this problem.