# laravel not load resources

Tags: laravel, npm

I have a project, the caul all the operative part works. But when displaying images, loading resources, the elements are recognized by the browser, they are transferred, but they are not read.
[navegator net log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42lSA.png)

I have reinstalled laravel, composer, npm and nothing works. The result is the same.

composer.json

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.65",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.5",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.5",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": 
        [
            "laravel/dusk"
        ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

package.json

```
    {
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.2.1",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.1.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "esrecurse": "^4.3.0",
        "internal-ip": "^7.0.0",
        "querystring": "^0.2.1"
    }
}
```

The app.js is not loading me either
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vJGs.png)

Comment: Hi, okay so please try adding the app.js as follows and test it `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` in your main layouts file. If you're already doing this, are you running `npm run watch` (once) or `npm run dev` each time you add code to the JS file?

Comment: I detected that I had a very old version of node, I just upgraded to version 17.3.0 and npm version 8.3.0.

When executing: npm run watch I have the output:
> watch
> mix watch

sh: 1: mix: not found

and when executing npm run dev
> dev
> npm run development
> development
> mix

sh: 1: mix: not found

I have seen other other links (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65718391/laravel-npm-command-mix-not-found) and they recommend removing node_modules, reinstalling and adding other packages.
The result is the same :(

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like a case where you may need to overhaul the entire environment to remove the corrupted parts which may have gotten worse and reinstalling and adding other packages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem persisted, I had to lower the laravel version to 7, install nodejs version 16, npm version 8.

Remove directories: node_modules and vendor.
Delete the files: package-lock.json and composer.lock

Then run:
composer install
npm install && npm run dev

I upgraded to Laravel version 8
composer update (resolve all dependencies)
npm install && npm run dev

And there it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Update your laravel-mix

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest
```

Clean npm install

```
npm clean-install
```

Then run

```
npm install && npm run dev
```